# creating bar diagrams using CSS only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a bar diagram using CSS. I refereed from the site::
https://css-tricks.com/making-charts-with-css/

But I am not getting the bars.
My code:

```
<style type="text/css">
dl {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

dt {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.text {
  font-weight: 600;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.percentage {
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
  to right,
  #ddd,
  #ddd 1px,
  #fff 1px,
  #fff 5%
);
  
  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #3d9970;
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:hover,
  &:focus {
    &:after {
       background-color: #aaa; 
    }
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .percentage-#{$i} {
    &:after {
      $value: ($i * 1%);
      width: $value;
    }
  }
}

html, body {
  height: 500px;
  font-family: "fira-sans-2",sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- Content Here -->
<dl>
  <dt>
    Browser market share June 2015
  </dt>
  <dd class="percentage percentage-11"><span class="text">IE 11: 11.33%</span></dd>
  <dd class="percentage percentage-49"><span class="text">Chrome: 49.77%</span></dd>
  <dd class="percentage percentage-16"><span class="text">Firefox: 16.09%</span></dd>
  <dd class="percentage percentage-5"><span class="text">Safari: 5.41%</span></dd>
  <dd class="percentage percentage-2"><span class="text">Opera: 1.62%</span></dd>
  <dd class="percentage percentage-2"><span class="text">Android 4.4: 2%</span></dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS code is SASS or LESS code. Do you use a CSS preprocessor at all?

Comment: @cloned please don't convert a SASS/LESS code to a snippet.

Comment: As the others has stated, you are not using regular CSS, but are using SASS (with SCSS sintax) which is mentioned on the article you referenced.
Remeber to research a little before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

This part here is not CSS, [it's SCSS w](https://sass-lang.com)hich needs to get converted to CSS.

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
  .percentage-#{$i} {
    &:after {
      $value: ($i * 1%);
      width: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically this generates the following CSS, for values from value 1 to 100:

```
 .percentage-1:after {
   width: 1%;
  }

 .percentage-2:after {
   width: 2%;
  } /* and so on, until 100% */
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using CSS preprocessor code (SCSS), but don't run the software needed for that. So you cade with the ampersand characters (`&`) and your `@for` loop don't translate to proper CSS code.

I did this by hand for your code below (skipped a few lines for the 100 lines of percentage selectors)

```css
dl {
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
}

dt {
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 130px;
}

.text {
  font-weight: 600;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.percentage {
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 130px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( to right, #ddd, #ddd 1px, #fff 1px, #fff 5%);
}
.percentage:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background-color: #3d9970;
    width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.percentage:hover:after,
.percentage:focus:after {
      background-color: #aaa;
}

.percentage-1:after { width: 1%; }
.percentage-2:after { width: 2%; }
.percentage-3:after { width: 3%; }
.percentage-4:after { width: 4%; }
.percentage-5:after { width: 5%; }
.percentage-6:after { width: 6%; }
/* ... */
.percentage-11:after { width: 11%; }
.percentage-16:after { width: 16%; }
.percentage-49:after { width: 49%; }
/* ... */
.percentage-96:after { width: 96%; }
.percentage-97:after { width: 97%; }
.percentage-98:after { width: 98%; }
.percentage-99:after { width: 99%; }
.percentage-100:after { width: 100%; }



html,
body {
  height: 500px;
  font-family: "fira-sans-2", sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- Content Here -->
  <dl>
    <dt>
        Browser market share June 2015
      </dt>
    <dd class="percentage percentage-11"><span class="text">IE 11: 11.33%</span></dd>
    <dd class="percentage percentage-49"><span class="text">Chrome: 49.77%</span></dd>
    <dd class="percentage percentage-16"><span class="text">Firefox: 16.09%</span></dd>
    <dd class="percentage percentage-5"><span class="text">Safari: 5.41%</span></dd>
    <dd class="percentage percentage-2"><span class="text">Opera: 1.62%</span></dd>
    <dd class="percentage percentage-2"><span class="text">Android 4.4: 2%</span></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not CSS, it's [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/) which has to be compiled to regular CSS.
If you don't know how about SASS, search for tools to compile it to regular CSS like [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/).